# Sentences that end in a pronoun

Tags: translation, usage

A type of sentence or clause which seems to be common is one that has a long pre-modifying clause in front of a pronoun or a proper noun.

Example from a blog post:

塗装したいものがたくさんあるのに、塗料を決められない、色が決められない、高いのはイヤ、という三重苦でまったく進まない私。

What sort of sense does this convey, esp. comparing to sentences where the pronoun/proper noun is a が-marked subject or は-marked topic instead? How is that sense usually translated?